# Add bootstrap/jquery datepicker to MVC 5 razor view

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I've tried a lot of examples. They seems to be quite simple but I can not get it working. I have just simple textbox and then I click on it it does not react. Following scripts are included:

```
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Styles

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Model

```
[Display(Name = "OrderDate")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    @section scripts {

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(".datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>

    }

    ...

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDate);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker" , @id = "datepicker" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Console says: `TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Put it in $(document).ready

Comment: didn't help. The same error.

Comment: The script you have included is `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` which assuming you want to use that, then its `$(".datepicker").datetimepicker();` (not `datepicker()`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
http://localhost:50804/Content/themes/base/css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OrderDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker" , @id = "datepicker" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Datapicker is part of [JqueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), but in your code snippet there is no reference of JqueryUI library.

Here is the [link for installing jqueryui using NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined)

It is always good practice to use document.ready for tagging events wherever required.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`datepicker()` is not in JQuery.  It is in JQueryUI.  I don't see it in your code sample, so I'm assuming that this is where the problem lies.

`Install-package JQuery.ui.combined` from the package manager console

And then add a script reference (before your script) to the jquery.ui.{version}.js that is then added.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker({

            //minDate: new Date(),
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/Content/Themes/images/date.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Select date",
            onSelect: function (selected_date) {
                var selectedDate = new Date(selected_date);
                var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
                $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);
            }
        });

        $('#EndDate').datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/Content/Themes/images/date.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Select date",
        });


    });


</script>
```

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Startdate, new { @class = "form-control placeholder-fix required", @type = "text", @autocomplete = "off", @placeholder = "Start Date" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Enddate, new { @class = "form-control placeholder-fix required", @type = "text", @autocomplete = "off", @placeholder = "End Date" })